# How to prevent excess image link area due to padding

Tags: html, css

I want to have an image link at the lower left side of my webpage. I am able to get the link to work but the entire space within the `padding` is also part of the link. So there is pretty much a big 800px by 800px link on my page when I only want the image itself to be a clickable link. Also, the position needs to be absolute because of the way the entire page is set up. Would anybody be able to tell me now to fix this?

```
<div id="image_link">
    <a href="#">
        <img id="image_id" src="../path/image">
    </a>
</div>
```

---

```
<style>
    #image_link {
        padding: 800px 0px 0px 800px;
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strange that it creates 800x800 pixels link area for you. `padding` on the `div` adds space inside the `div`, but outside the `a`, so it shouldn't make the `a` element larger.

But as you're already using `position: absolute;`, you should really use `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` to control the position. And it's recommended to set it on the `img` element directly.

```
#image_id {
    position: absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left: 800px;
}
```